# Question related to definite article

Tags: grammar, articles, parts-of-speech, writing

Why is "the" put before the words Internet and kitchen when they're used in general sense? For instance,

1. Women should stay in the kitchen.
2. The Internet is man's greatest creation.

Comment: “The kitchen” is a generic. The Internet is just . . . the Internet. Like the atmosphere. Separate systems are called intranets.

Comment: Anyway, I think Al Gore took credit for the Internet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Definite article — “on television” vs. “on the radio”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7479/definite-article-on-television-vs-on-the-radio) @Cerberus's answer looks at more general cases of generic usages of articles.