# Why "the" in "teach the 3rd grade"?

Tags: definite-articles

When asked "What do you do?", I understand it's idiomatic to say both:

1. "I teach *the* 3rd grade"
2. "I teach 3rd grade"

Note that the former can be used even as a general answer, not just as meaning "I teach the 3rd grade of school X". In that case, what does the "the" mean?

Inspired by [Why "the" in "looking in the mirror"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/559823)

Comment: The version without the article *is* idiomatic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why "the" in "looking in the mirror"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/559823/why-the-in-looking-in-the-mirror)

Comment: @Lawrence: No, that was the question that inspired mine, and I noted that. I didn't realize the other version is idiomatic, I'll rephrase so the question is about the difference.

Comment: Your alternative sense informs the more generic usage too, making it less impersonal.