# "One-Day Only Promotion" or "One-Day-Only Promotion"

Tags: hyphenation, compounds, modifiers, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

A copywriter I'm working with wrote "One-Day Only Promotion" but my feeling is that "One-Day-Only Promotion" is correct. The first three words describe 'Promotion'. I know you don't hyphenate adverbs, but does that apply when one is part of a compound adjective?

Comment: http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp - Rule 4 agrees with you, I'm a bit confused about Rule 5 regarding the adverbs ending in `ly` and whether `only` matches this context. I think not, and so you're probably right with "One-Day-Only".

Comment: @JoseK, put it in answer, I want to upvote it and give credit as answer to my [Aren't adverbs related to the closest word? What about other modifiers?](
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10626/arent-adverbs-related-to-the-closest-word-what-about-other-modifiers/12295#12295)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be *one-day-only promotion*, for the reason you reported.

> Have a look at some more genuine, authentic, certified, they-really-happened hyphos (a word we've made up on the model of *typos*): *sung-lasses*, *barf-lies*, *warp-lanes*, *doork-nobes*, *broom-sticks*, *pre-gnant*, *air-trips*, *boot-traps*, *stars-truck*, *sli-pup*, *ong-oing*. —*Comma sense*, Richard Lederer, John Shore

Answer (score 3):

I agree that "One-Day-Only" would be correct.

But copywriting is the Niagara Falls of bad grammar, so I've grown used to poor usage there. I often see this as "One Day Only Promotion" and my hide has been thickened over time to the point where it doesn't hurt me any longer.

**Addendum**

It is normal practice, in journalism at least, to consider the first compound noun in a compound adjective as a complete entity, so only one would be used. For example,

> New York-style pizza

Nevertheless, if the compound modifier is long (and the first part is not a proper noun), it is not uncommon to hyphenate all single words in it.