# "Hardware-counter-based tools" or "hardware-counter based tools"?

Tags: hyphenation, compound-adjectives

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Chainsaw-equipped or chainsaw equipped?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4761/chainsaw-equipped-or-chainsaw-equipped)
>   [How to connect a word and a phrase with a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/how-to-connect-a-word-and-a-phrase-with-a-dash)
>   ["One-Day Only Promotion" or "One-Day-Only Promotion"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11780/one-day-only-promotion-or-one-day-only-promotion)

Which is more correct?

> Hardware-counter-based tools

or

> Hardware-counter based tools

I don't even know exactly if I should put *hardware-counter* or *hardware-counters*.

Comment: @Julian could you help by explaining exactly what a *hardware-counter (-) based tool* is?

Comment: HOpe [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_performance_counter) helps, @snumpy

Comment: @snumpy A piece of software that measures hardware counters. If you want to go into the details, take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_performance_counter :)

Comment: LOL, that was the exact same link @Julian!

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Chainsaw-equipped or chainsaw equipped?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4761/chainsaw-equipped-or-chainsaw-equipped); [Should I use “ related” or “-related”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2908/should-i-use-related-or-related)

Comment: Part of this question is similar to two of the three listed as duplicates, and part similar to the third, but there's a distance between similar and duplicate. None of them are about the question of making a hyphenated phrase from terms where one is already hyphenated, as this does, and as The Raven answers well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is tricky because it is solved with a mark of punctuation called the "en-dash." Its length is longer than a hyphen and shorter than a full em-dash. It's the middle one in this series: - – —

So with a term like "Hardware-counter-based tools" the solution is to use an en-dash between "counter" and "based," which signifies that the modifier "based" should apply to both words preceding it:

> Hardware counter–based tools

Otherwise, the en-dash is used to indicate spans or ranges between units: 9:00–10:00, etc.

Comment: I'm setting this as the accepting answer. I think there is no need to put a hyphen between _hardware_ and _counter_ for disambiguation, as _hardware counter_ is a pretty known term (in this context).

Answer (score 3):

The Raven is close but not quite there yet. "Hardware counter based" is a compound [attributive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective#Form) adjective and needs both a hyphen and an en-dash:

> This is a hardware-counter–based tool.

A hyphen is usually needed when using a [compound adjective](http://www.uhv.edu/ac/newsletters/writing/grammartip2004.11.30.htm):

> This is a counter-based tool.

The **hyphen–en-dash combo** is needed when one of the elements in the compound adjective is itself a compound. This helps the reader identify which of the words are associated with each other:

> { [ ( hardware ) - ( counter ) ] – ( based ) } tool

Not that the hyphen would be unnecessary if the phrase were used as a predicative adjective:

> This tool is hardware counter–based.

Comment: Your proposal is sound, but a bit overcomplicated, isn't it? Two kinds of dashes in the same phrase!? Wow! :) And why the hyphen is unnecessary if the phrase is used as a predicative adjective?

Comment: @Julian that's answered in the answer to [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2908/should-i-use-related-or-related)... I think...

Comment: Doug, take a look at the examples given here: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/dash.htm In particular, "a White House–backed proposal" accords with the response I've given. I'd more happily allow the hyphen+en-dash solution for a term that is already hyphenated being used as a modifier.

Comment: The reason for the hyphen in a compound modifier, the reason for the en-dash in a compound compound modifier, and the reason no dash is needed in "White House" are all the same reason: disambiguation. There may be more important reasons, but this is the more-important reason. A "cold-case worker" is not the same thing as a "cold case worker." But a "White House pet" will never be confused with a "white house pet."

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to tools that are based on hardware-counters, I think it should be:

> Hardware-counter based tools

There's no real need for the hyphen between "counter" and "based"

Comment: I may be mistaken here, but would you not say *hardware-based tool* or *counter-based tool*?  Besides, in the article you and the OP provided *hardware counter* does not have a dash.

Comment: In that article, "hardware counter" was being used as a noun, whereas in this case, it is being used as a compound modifier

Comment: The answers for both questions linked by @MrHen suggest that there needs to be a dash before *based*

Comment: They only had two modifiers in that compound modifier. This has three

Comment: I'm afraid I find Raven's and Doug's answers far more plausible.