# Game-development-oriented or game development-oriented?

Tags: adjectives, hyphenation, compound-adjectives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to connect a word and a phrase with a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/how-to-connect-a-word-and-a-phrase-with-a-hyphen)
>   [“Hardware-counter-based tools” or “hardware-counter based tools”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29036/hardware-counter-based-tools-or-hardware-counter-based-tools)

As the title states, which is the correct hyphenation of the adjective formed by multiple words? Is it **"game development-oriented"** or **"game-development-oriented"**?

By "game development-oriented" or "game-development-oriented", I refer to something that is oriented towards game development.

Sample usage:

> The company's year-long plan is more *game development-oriented (game-development-oriented)* this year compared to last year.

Answer (score 1):

Neither seems a particularly effective way of expressing the idea. I would instead suggest something like ‘The company's year-long plan is to concentrate more on developing games this year compared to last year.’